# Textarea inside fieldset results in different margin/padding

Tags: html, css

I would like a textarea inside a fieldset to expand to the full width:

HTML

```
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Legendary</legend>
    <textarea>I'm supposed to fill the fieldset, but the padding/margin isn't the same.</textarea>
    <div></div>
  </fieldset>
```

CSS

```
textarea{width: 100%;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gL8bjtv9/4/

However, the left/right gaps (padding/margin) between the elements are different (Firefox, Chrome).

Why does this occur, and how can it be fixed?

---

Also: if I change the textarea's width from "100%" (1588px computed) to "1588px" in Firefox's Inspector, it seems OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (browser-specific rules): https://stackoverflow.com/a/6796064/1619432

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Seems to work for Firefox, too.

Comment: Accepting my own answer to mark this question as solved (based on timestamp), linking the previous question's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla web docs explains `box-sizing` best: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

```
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;
border: solid #5B6DCD 10px;
padding: 5px;
```

You can also play around with their great `box-sizing` visual tool to assist in understanding the CSS property better.

Answer (score -1):

You could try doing this

```
textarea {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

or just adjust the rows attribute till it fits

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="4">I'm supposed to fill the fieldset, but the padding/margin isn't the same.</textarea>
```

Comment: -1: Sorry, but there's no point in copying the answer I linked, or hardcoding values (try changing your browser window size to see what I mean).

Comment: You obviously can't see I added a rows and cols attr @handle

Comment: I did see that and called it hardcoding.